# nsfetchrequestcontroller.request

Tags: objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is it okay to change that thing if we are not using the cache anyway?

To repeat, we're not supposed to change the fetchrequestcontroller request only if we do not use the cache right?

If I am displaying a table based on user search and the search change, should I create a whole new fetchrequestcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states "You must not reuse the same fetched results controller for multiple queries unless you set the cacheName to nil". It also states you should delete the cache if modifying the fetch request.  I often use two different caches depending on the application.  You can read more about [NSFetchedResultsController here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it's [delegate here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: In other word, if the cacheName is nil then everything is fine right? I want to make sure of that.

Comment: Historically it has been for me, yes.